# Can't create a primary, not a logical partition in SD Card

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, partitions, link2sd, ext4

### 1. Summary

I can't set primary, not logical partition in my SD Card.

After my attempts, I can't write anything to SD Card.

---

### 2. Hardware and software

#### 2.1. Smartphone

1. ARK Benefit S401,
2. Android 5.1.1,
3. CyanogenMod 12.1 ROM,
4. Rooted, Busybox installed,
5. TWRP Recovery,
6. Successful worked with another and non-mounted SD Cards.

#### 2.2. PC

1. Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB EN,
2. MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition 10.0,
3. EaseUS Partition Master (Free) 12.8.

#### 2.3. SD Card

1. OSMR 8 GB (7,5 de-facto),
2. 10 class,
3. Error checking:

   [image: Error checking]
4. Surface Test:

   [image: Surface]
5. I have card reader as well.

---

### 3. Steps to reproduce

#### 3.1. Reason

I have 1,7 GB User Partition in my phone, it's not enough for me. I want to move my apk + dex + lib files to SD Card. [**I read**](http://www.link2sd.info/faq), that I need to use Link2SD and to create new primary partition in my SD Card.

#### 3.2. Partition creating

I create backup all my MicroSD data.

I try to create partitions, use these instructions:

1. [**How to use Link2SD App for Partition SD Card — Full Guide**](https://link2sd.co/link2sd-partition-sd-card/),
2. [**[TUT]How to Create Partition in SD card/MicroSD for Windows user**](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2117275).

[image: Operations]
[image: Ext4]
[image: Apply pending]

---

### 4. Result

1. I select primary, but in result I get logical, not primary partition:

   [image: Not primary]
2. I can't move my apk + lib + dex to SD Card:

   > Second partition not found

   [image: Link2SD]
3. After my operations I can't to make screenshots, download applications to SD Card. I probably can't write any data to SD card. I get errors:

   > Can't take screenshot due to limited storage space, or it isn't allowed by the app or your organization
   >
   > Mod.apk_download: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

---

### 5. Not helped

1. I create logical, not primary partition for 2,5 GB again.
2. I create ext2 and ext3 partitions instead of ext4.
3. I try partition recovery:

[image: Recovery1]

[image: Recovery2]

[image: Recovery3]

---

### 6. Formatting

#### 1. SD Memory Card Formation

I try format my SDCard use [**SD Memory Card Formation**](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/). Quick and overwrite formatting failed.

[image: Quick]
[image: Overwrite]

#### 2. Diskpart

I try to format my MicroSD use [**diskpart**](https://www.wintips.org/fix-windows-was-unable-to-complete-format-disk-is-write-protected/):

```
C:\System Volume Information>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.14393.0

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: DESKTOP-EEOT0TN

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB  4096 KB
  Disk 1    Online         7681 MB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Disk attributes cleared successfully.

DISKPART> select partition 1

Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> active

DiskPart marked the current partition as active.

DISKPART> format fs=fat32

    0 percent completed

DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> exit

Leaving DiskPart...
```

#### 3. chkdsk

```
chkdsk g: /f /r
The type of the file system is FAT32.
Volume Serial Number is 0352-6F30
Windows is verifying files and folders...
File and folder verification is complete.
Windows is verifying free space...
Free space verification is complete.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.
    5,231,600 KB total disk space.
            4 KB in 2 hidden files.
        1,236 KB in 295 folders.
    1,902,568 KB in 1,076 files.
    3,327,788 KB are available.

        4,096 bytes in each allocation unit.
    1,307,900 total allocation units on disk.
      831,947 allocation units available on disk.
Cannot write boot sector.
```

#### 4. HDD Low Level Format Tool

After these actions nothing has changed.

[image: HDD1]

[image: HDD2]

---

### 7. Do not offer

1. Please do not suggest me to buy new telephone/SD Card/PC.

Comment: I would have tried to `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M count=1` to clear out any traces of corrupted partition info that may cause lesser tools to fail format the card. In case `dd` fails, you can be pretty sure to have hardware problem with the card. In addition, the `S` in the SD card name refers to "Secure" - SD cards can be put to permanent read only state (either full storage space or partially) and if some misbehaving software has done that, there's no way to undo. In practice, that belongs to "broken hardware" case, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Answer

Unfortunately, in this case you need buy a new SD Card.

---

### 2. Argumentation

- [**4pda post**](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=309190):

> Если у вас не записываются новые данные на карту, а старые после удаления появляются вновь, и форматирование не помогает — карта труп, и восстановить её не удастся!

Translate on English:

**If**:

1. New data don't write to SD Card (4.3 item of my question)
2. Old data show again
3. Formatting doesn't help (6 item)

**That**:

- You lost your SD Card.

I could not refute this in my case.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear. You're not going to move Dalvik Cache to sdcard because the Dalvik Virtual Machine is set to prepare application classes cache to the data partition that claims your internal storage. You can move the app files to sd because they are in the user end but the dalvik cache is managed from the system end by DVM. You can create the partition but having system apps' classes there, there ain't a way. Or did you just mean apps to sd? Which is possible?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read [**Link2SD FAQ**](http://www.link2sd.info/faq): // **Native apps2sd** — this method moves apk + lib files on Android 2.3+ // **Link2SD** — Link2SD moves apk + dex + lib files of the application to the second partition and creates symbolic links in the original locations on internal storage. // I want to move to my SD Card apk + dex + lib files.

Comment: I got you now what you meant

Comment: I [**edit**](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/187789/revisions) the question, based on your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. It's now more clearer. I see you're using computer, is there any other way to have this done locally on phone?

Comment: Now I can't download any apps to my phone, see 4.3 item( .

Comment: The sdcard you're talking about. Is it an external sd or the inbuilt internal storage. Because if its the external it won't affect phone downloads. And if its the internal, that is too low because of partitioning, you need to repair the file system using TWRP. But after doing some settings, if yiur device has a twrp made for it

Comment: **1.** I use TWRP recovery. // **2.** I use [**custom boot**](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=788444&st=80#entry55986424) with memory substitution (memory replace). That is I loaded the apps and saved screenshots/screencasts on the external SD Card.

Comment: If incase the partition you created is a ROFS or any ROFS. You can use adb to mount it as RW. These codes: Incase the data part is now RO, you can use|           su && mount -o remount,rw /data && mount -o remount,rw /data/media | since you have root. See if you can copy something to it if so, just backup all /data partition and format it then restore it with TWRP

Comment: Here it seems there are two solutions which you may need. Do you want to make link to sd work or you just want to revert and make file system readable again

Comment: I can't format my SD Card, I [**update**](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/187789/revisions) my question.

Comment: **1.** I want, that my SD Card at least worked as before. // **2.** If it possible, I want to create 2 primary partitions for successful Link2SD usage.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to try to make the sdcard workable. Try to make file system using adb while sd is on your phone to see if it goes through. Commands: mkfs.vfat -v /external-sdcard or mkfs.ext2 -v /external-sdcard I'm assuming this is how your phone calls external sd from the root folder and follow the steps more kinly to make link to sd work again